# Save NSMutableArray in a file

Tags: objective-c, ipad, nsmutablearray

I am trying to save one `NSMutableArray` with Objects into a file. There is no error and when I debugged the code the object Recipe always has a content is never empty, however productsList never adds this object... I am getting crazy with that, some Ideas ?

```
#import "Utils.h"
#import "Recipe.h"

@implementation Utils
{

NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *dataFilePath;

}

-(Utils*) init {
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    // Build the path to the data file
    dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"wish.info"]];

}

return self;
}

-(NSMutableArray * )loadProducts{

return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:dataFilePath];
}
-(void) saveProducts: (NSMutableArray * ) productsList{
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:productsList toFile:dataFilePath];

NSLog(@"Products List%@",productsList);
}

-(void) addProduct: (Recipe*) recipe{

NSMutableArray *productsList = [self loadProducts];

[productsList addObject:recipe];

[self saveProducts:productsList];
}
-(void) deleteProduct: (Recipe*) recipe{
NSMutableArray *productsList = [self loadProducts];

[productsList removeObject:recipe];

[self saveProducts:productsList];
}
-(Boolean) isSelected: (Recipe*) recipe{
return [[self loadProducts] containsObject:recipe];
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you made sure your Recipe class implements the NSCoding protocol?

Comment: Thank you for your help! i think that the problem is because this line return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:dataFilePath]; the first time return nil, so later I check if is nill and if it is, i set to [NSMutableArray new] looks than is working with that now. What is NSCoding protocol ? sorry I am new ...

Comment: Ok,I saw it. Yes I have it. The problem was here -(NSMutableArray * )loadProducts{

return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:dataFilePath];
}

Comment: Right, that will definitely cause the problem since you pass addObject: to nil which is valid but doesn't do anything.